# Not enough quote symbols for code?

Tags: php, javascript, html, quote

this is a pretty strange question, but what can i use as quotes in HTML or php or javascript?

I already use ' and " , but i need one more, cause i have javascript INSIDE html INSIDE php.

I need them when i don't use variables, but specific strings...

So.. What can i use as third kind of quote ?

Thanks

Evert

Comment: You can escape quotes using a backslash

Comment: He has a minimal understanding of the problem. He realizes that nested quotes makes life difficult. Very few people are aware of all the functions in PHP, so how can we blame him for asking a perfectly valid question, and close his question simply because he had never heard of heredoc syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) syntax:

```
$javascript = <<<EOT
//Enter javascript here

EOT;
```

Within the heredoc syntax, you can enter single and double quotes. The syntax starts with '<<<' and a unique identifier (in this case 'EOT') that appears nowhere else on you page, and it closes with the same identifIer and a semicolon. It's important that no spaces or anything else occur on the same line as the closing identifier.

For example, you could do the following:

```
$javascript = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hello world!");
    });
    //]]>
</script>

EOT;
```

Comment: (sorry, can't cote up, still need 2 reputations ;)